# Accessing the Uploaded Images from Parse, gives me Undefined File URL object

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am making an app with Parse Server and I uploaded images to the parse server,whenever I want to access those images from the Server, I am getting this error

**com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
unexpected url :     undefined/files/96592k7214c4q23824534f304bbc2b54a0f59b1ok/d50d595d21hell62480db6d5edb0aa1bf_fine%20wining.png**

Here is the Code

```java
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if(e==null) {
                    if (objects.size() > 0) {
                        MainActivity.showToast(String.valueOf(objects.size()), UserFeedActivity.this);

                        Log.i("Objects are: ",String.format("%s",objects));
                        for (ParseObject object : objects) {

                            ParseFile file = object.getParseFile("image”);
                            //Here Error Occurs

                            Log.i("OBJECT URL",file.getUrl());
                            file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {
                                        if (data.length > 0) {
                                                        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
                                                        BytesList.add(bitmap);
                                                }
                                    } else {
                                         MainActivity.showToast(e.getMessage(),UserFeedActivity.this);
                                    }
```

Comment: You are trying to parse the url that is not valid.

Comment: I am getting the file URL from Parse Object, I am not giving static URL

Comment: looks like your "parse server" is written in javascript. if that's the case, pretty sure the problem is in your server logic.

Comment: No it is in Java

Comment: then why does your url start with `undefined`?

Comment: that’s the question bro